# SOme help with launch files

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In response to a request for the launch file and the error. Here is the launch file,

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="newrobot" type="/src/usb.py" name='base_scan' output="screen">
  </node>

  <node pkg="newrobot" type="src/odompublish.py" name="odom" output="screen">
  </node>

  <node pkg="newrobot" type="src/odompublish.py" name="base_pos" output="screen">
  </node>
</launch>
```

And the error message

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [newrobot/src/usb.py]: newrobot
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [newrobot/src/odompublish.py]: newrobot
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [newrobot/src/odompublish.py]: newrobot
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102086/some-help-with-launch-files/) by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2013-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2013-11-17**:
Can you post the .launch file you are trying to launch and the full error you get?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-11-17**:
`type` is the binary to launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Remove all the paths in the type, e.g. /src/usb.py should be usb.py. ROS finds this by itself.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-11-18**:
Also, since you are using Python-based nodes, make sure that your files have executable permissions or ROS won't find nodes of that type e.g. `chmod a+x [PATH_ON_ROS_PACKAGE_PATH]/newrobot/src/usb.py`

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-11-18**:
one question I use a class for the laser scan publisher that called within usb. Do I use usb ore the node that makes up the class?

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-11-18**:
IS the catkin workspace suppose to be the ROS directory? I got mine in seperate. Could be what causing the problem

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-11-18**:
As @dornhege mentioned above, the `type` field is the Python script to run.  Regardless of how imports are structured and what classes are involved, the "top-level" script is what goes in the `type` field.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-11-18**:
Let's say your catkin ws is at *~/catkin_ws/*, then your package should be in *~/catkin_ws/src/*.  Therefore, one of your example nodes would be *~/catkin_ws/src/newrobot/src/usb.py*.  If everything is working, TAB key should autocomplete both the package name, and the nodename when using `rosrun`.

**Comment by [Massbuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/6726/massbuilder/) on 2013-11-19**:
Seems the tab is not working, is there another way to find the package path

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-11-19**:
The command `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` will print out the current package path.  In the above example *~/catkin_ws/src*  should be listed in that output if it's not, try `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`.  I'm assuming you setup a workspace http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace